# Cypress Error "Attempted to wrap warn which is already wrapped"

Tags: typescript, cypress

**End goal:** Test for warnings and errors on the console using Cypress and Typescript.

**Current Error Message:** `Attempted to wrap warn which is already wrapped`.

**Code:**

```
  describe.only("Unauthenticated User", () => {
    it("No Console Errors for /", () => {
      cy.visit("/", { 
        onBeforeLoad(win) { cy.spy(win.console, 'error').as('onBeforeLoadSpyWinConsoleError') },
        onLoad(win) { cy.spy(win.console, 'error').as('onLoadSpyWinConsoleError') } 
      });
      cy.get('@onBeforeLoadSpyWinConsoleError').should('have.callCount', 0); 
      cy.get('@onLoadSpyWinConsoleError').should('have.callCount', 0); 
    });
    it("No Console Warns for /", () => {
      cy.visit("/", { 
        onBeforeLoad(win) { cy.spy(win.console, 'warn').as('onBeforeLoadSpyWinConsoleWarn') },
        onLoad(win) { cy.spy(win.console, 'warn').as('onLoadSpyWinConsoleWarn') } 
      });
      cy.get('@onBeforeLoadSpyWinConsoleWarn').should('have.callCount', 0); 
      cy.get('@onLoadSpyWinConsoleWarn').should('have.callCount', 0); 
    });
  });
```

Could someone please offer not only a solution to fix the error, but also some suggestions to remove the code duplication? Any documentation would be great to understand the error more in depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored the code and only offered `onBeforeLoad()` as a means to look for console errors and warnings.

**I wrote this function:**

```
function checkConsole(page: string, type: keyof Console){
  cy.visit(page, { onBeforeLoad(win) { cy.spy(win.console, type).as(type) }});
  cy.get(`@${type}`).should('have.callCount', 0); 
}
```

**And passed it into my tests like so:**

```
  describe("Unauthenticated User", () => {
    it("No Console Errors for /", () => checkConsole("/", "error"));
    it("No Console Warns for /", () => checkConsole("/", "warn"));
  });
```

This destructured the code enough, but not too much so others will not understand.

Answer (score 2):

Spys are "listeners" and will persist throughout the test. You should be fine with `beforeLoad` only

```js
  describe.only("Unauthenticated User", () => {
    it("No Console Errors for /", () => {
      cy.visit("/", { 
        onBeforeLoad(win) { cy.spy(win.console, 'error').as('onBeforeLoadSpyWinConsoleError') },
      });
      cy.get('@onBeforeLoadSpyWinConsoleError').should('have.callCount', 0); 
    });
    it("No Console Warns for /", () => {
      cy.visit("/", { 
        onBeforeLoad(win) { cy.spy(win.console, 'warn').as('onBeforeLoadSpyWinConsoleWarn') },
      });
      cy.get('@onBeforeLoadSpyWinConsoleWarn').should('have.callCount', 0); 
    });
  });
```